# Capturing piratebay move torrents with keywords

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture piratebays recent movies https://thepiratebay.org/browse/201/0/3

I'm trying to capture: movie title, year (2018,2017), fileformat (xvid, x264), rip source (dvdrip, hdrip, bluray) and the magnet link

And I want to be able to easily set the filters, so preferably with one array

This is what I currently got:

```
for (.*).*(2018|2017|bluray|bdrip|blu-ray|xvid).*(2018|2017|bluray|bdrip|blu-ray|xvid).*(2018|2017|bluray|bdrip|blu-ray|xvid).*\n.*\n<a href="([^"]*)
```

With /i flag set.

The title is capture fine apart from that ( is sometimes captured. The year is captured fine. But then it messes up and captures 2 times the same thing: eg:

```
Movie: Mission Impossible Fallout
Keyword 1 (year): 2018
Keyword 2: XViD
Keyword 3: XViD
magnet: magnet:?...
```

Comment: Use HTML parser and then parse titles with Regex.

Answer (score 0):

I went with

```
for ([^(\["]+(2018|2017)).*\n.*\n<a href="([^"]*)
```

Perfectly captures the title along with the year and magnet. I will check for keywords with an if in statement on .groups()